# How to make the HTML occupie the whole page using Angular 9?

Tags: html, css, angular

When I run the following lines using just HTML and CSS it runs as I want it, with the header having no margins:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.header{
    background-color: purple;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class='header'>
    <h1>Any text</h1>
</div>
```

But in Angular 9, when I write the same code on a component's HTML and CSS files, it does't occupies the whole page, it have a margin of some pixels instead. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Angular add own tags so check with DevTool to see if have angular host tags and if your style is correctly added to component or global.